# Nginx remove special character

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, location

My URL is: https://example.com/data=123456

I added the following line of code to the index.php file: var_dump($_GET['data']);
But this only works if I add a ? character to the URL.
(example: https://example.com/?data=123456)
This is in the root of index.php.

I tried to add this to the nginx.conf file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^(.*)\?(.*)$ $1$2 last; 
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    rewrite ^(.*)\?(.*)$ $1$2 last; 
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

But not working. How to remove the "?" character from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your URL is `https://example.com/data=123456`, the `data=123456` is a part of URL **path**. When your URL is `https://example.com/?data=123456`, the `data=123456` is a **query** part of the URL, where query argument `data` has a value if `123456`. Check at least the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Next, only query arguments can be accesses via `$_GET` array. Full request URI (including both path and query parts) is available via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. You can analyze that variable in your PHP script and skip the rewrite part completely.

If you want to rewrite your URI and made that `data` to be accessible via `$_GET['data']` variable, it is also possible. However your main mistake is that the `rewrite` directive works only with (normalized) path of the given URL and not the query part of it. Nevertheless it can be used to append (or replace) query arguments. To do it you can use

```
rewrite ^(.*/)(data=[^/]*)$ $1?$2;
```

(to rewrite only `data` parameter) or more generic

```
rewrite ^(.*/)([^/=]+=[^/]*)$ $1?$2;
```

(to count on every `param=value` form of the URL path suffix). You can place this rewrite rule at the `server` configuration level.